# Why does my gas stove smell like burnt gas when turning on the oven and burners

Tags: appliances, gas, stove

I bought a gas stove over a year ago. I continually smell burnt gas. It has smelled since day 1.

Why does this happen and how do I stop it?

Comment: Have you had a gas stove before? Did you get it installed professionally, or do it yourself? Are there any leaks? Is it vented properly?

Comment: If it is a ventless or free air vent range it is requires a vent hood fan to be running during use.  Ours is five years old still smells.

Comment: Is it brand new? It may need to breaken-in. http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/49922/when-does-the-new-home-oven-stove-smell-go-away

Comment: That was a good link mysterfixit I had not had such a bad experience as some usually the stove off gasses in just a few cycles. +

Comment: "Burnt gas" shouldn't have a smell -- it's a very clean fuel.

Comment: @keshlam --  I suspect it's sulfur compounds that cause it (either unburnt odorant, or sulfur compounds produced when odorant burns)

Comment: @spicetraders  that's just not true.  Gas ranges / ovens do not require any sort of venting.

Comment: PLease clarify: do you smell whatever it is only when using the stove, or all the time?

Comment: @Carl Witthoft I will have to see if I can figure out where the owners manual is so I can photo copy the paragraph.  It clear stated that range is not direct vented and requires operation of a vent hood to assure safe use.

Comment: I suppose the appropriate odor here might be unburned gas, as keshlam suggests that burned gas has no smell.

Comment: Most residential gas ranges in the US do *not* require a vent hood for safe use, under normal circumstances.  I can't vouch for equipment/codes elsewhere. If combustion is occurring normally, the odorant added to gas (ethyl mercaptan) should burn off and there should be no odor, certainly not once the equipment has "burned in" (the first few uses). If there is an odor, I really doubt that it is from the gas per se... Unless you are leaking unburned gas, which is potentially a seriously dangerous situation and should be addressed by a pro.

Answer (score 1):

Have the orifice checked in the gas regulator. The will come with either a natural gas or propane orifice. Depending on what you have in the way of gas, you may need them swapped. The spare orifices are stored with the regulator.

We had the same problem when we moved in to our house. It came with a new stove, the house has propane, but the smell got progressively worse and the oven was sooted up. We called the installer and the came and swapped out the orifices, problem solved.